# Use sources files from jar in my webApp

Tags: jakarta-ee, jar

I need my webapp to use the class files in the jar I produced instead of the directory /classes.
If I add my jar to the lib directory, will my application run without having to add a mapping to my web.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source code is for humans, not for webapps. You need to compile the classes, package them into a jar file and place it inside `WEB-INF/lib`.

**Edit:**

If you put the jar file inside the `WEB-INF/lib` directory, the webapp will pick it up automatically. No need to add anything to the `web.xml`.

Comment: I see now. Updated the answer :)